# How to find method for handling object file in python package trading-calander

Tags: python, object

I have installed package from https://pypi.org/project/trading-calendars/

When i run `get_calendar('XNYS')` it produces and object file. How can find out what method does this object have for viewing data? The reason i am asking is because in this case in the documentation shows no examples on its [usage](https://github.com/quantopian/trading_calendars/issues/107).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read the documentation. If there is none, the module is ... well ... crap. In such case do `print(obj.__dict__)` to see all the properties of the object, and if anything is of use to you. Worst come to worst, read the source code of the module on Github.

[Here](https://www.zipline.io/appendix.html#trading-calendar-api) is the documentation as mentioned in [`trading_calendars#107`](https://github.com/quantopian/trading_calendars/issues/107) (found by going to Issues and searching "documentation", for future reference).